# JAVA - Get access to a file in different subfolder

Tags: java, file, directory, datagram

I am programming a file transfer, and i am having troubles with it.
In my current location i have created a folder called "Server Folder", where i will have files that the Client can transfer (I will be transfered with the same name, to the workspace directory), But every time i try to access it, it fails.

```
FILE_SERVER_PATH = "./ServerFolder/";

File fileToRead = new File(FILE_SERVER_PATH + fileName);
        fileToRead = fileToRead.getParentFile();


        if(fileToRead.exists()){
            FileInputStream readingBuffer = new FileInputStream(fileToRead);
```

fileName is received throw datagram, and the name is correct. It always fails in the condition --> fileToRead.exists()

Can anyone please give me a tip?

Thx! :-)

Comment: Do you mean `FILE_SERVER_PATH = "./Server Folder/"`? -Note the space

Comment: Also, you're generating a file name with a double slash, and you're trying to read the server folder itself (since you're calling `getParentFile()` on the child file and reading this parent file).

Comment: As written, your code generates the path "./Server Folder//[fileName]" where [fileName] is the value of the fileName variable.  This seems wrong (note the double forward slash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the folder path as absolute.

will help and work...current directory works only if you know in which directory you are in at the time of execution.